# 404 ERROR when I try to GET data from google spreadsheet

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Hy everyone, I don't know if exit someone who can help me.

I don't know how it is possible, few days ago all ok now it stop to work.
Basically I read data in a html table on a website from a google spreadsheet public on website and public to everyone with the link. Using ajax.

Until now it worked, i saw all the datas and voices presents on my sheet in google drive, now it stop to show the datas and return an anonymous error like if the link to my google spreadsheet is inexistent, but it is here!!

For example on this googlesheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KmAf2uc13fWxPvn8dtk9j9kOL3nCVqi8H-wYau6Tww/edit?usp=sharing

I Have a series of data to display on my html website. Until few days ago it worked, now no.

I used jquery google : src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">

I public my code below:

```
<script>
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/13KmAf2uc13fWxPvn8dtk9j9kOL3nCVqi8H-wYau6Tww/od6/public/values?alt=json", function (data) {
  var sheetData = data.feed.entry;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {
    var nome = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$_cn6ca']['$t'];
    var ingredienti = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$_cokwr']['$t'];
    var prezzo = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$_cpzh4']['$t'];
    document.getElementById('Vinorosato').innerHTML += ('<div class="Teglie menu-restaurant">'+'<span class="clearfix">'+'<a class="menu-title" style="padding-right: 50px;">'+nome+'</a>'+'<span class="menu-price">'+prezzo+'</span>'+'</span>'+'<span class="menu-subtitle" style="padding-right: 100px;">'+ingredienti+'</span>'+'</div>');
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code that doesn't require jQuery

```
<html><body>
<script>

function reqListener () {
  var jsonString = this.responseText.match(/(?<="table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0];
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var table = '<table>'
  for (var i=0;i<json.rows.length;i++){
    var nome = json.rows[i].c[0].v;
    var ingredienti = json.rows[i].c[1].v;
    var prezzo = json.rows[i].c[2].v;
    table += '<tr><td>' + nome + '</td><td>' + ingredienti + '</td><td>' + prezzo + '&nbsp;&euro;</td></tr>'
  }
  table += '</table>'
  document.getElementById("Vinorosato").innerHTML = table;
}

var id = '13KmAf2uc13fWxPvn8dtk9j9kOL3nCVqi8H-wYau6Tww';
var gid = '0';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", url, true);
oReq.send();
 
</script>
<div id="Vinorosato">&nbsp;</div></body></html>
```

and adapt with your own style

Comment: Do you know why on web with android work and ios no?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest doesn't work on Safari, but you can now replace it by Chrome if needed (iso14). Or change the method I used to fectch data by asynchronous method.

Comment: Sorry do you have a link where i can study this method? I really need to use the code also on ios browser, also on Chrome or firefox  dosn't work if i open the website with iphone an that browser do you can help me? 
I thought was a ajax problem in a first moment but now... i don't know really well the asynchronus method for do this.

Comment: ok i will work on it, be patient (the purpose of my answer was mainly to give you the new url to use instead of feed method which is now deprecated). Does ajax/libs/jQuery you mentionned in your request works on Safari/iOS ?

Comment: in past yes, i ever used the jquery that i mentioned. your url work and i am really happy for that, is more than the all thing i done for fix the code in many many days, but  if i try to upload the code on web... with a computer o an android phone work, with any other browser on iphone no. 
We can work about togheter if you want. 

In past this libs worked https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js 
And now i think is always ok for our scope, it worked in past on safari and iOS

Comment: You probably need to post a new query on stackoverflow focused on ajax / jquery / ios as it seems like there is a problem for a lot of developers  https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+ios+problem , you will then have a faster response from the community. I will try to work on it in parallel but I have no experience on ios.

Comment: Test the other answer with iOs

Comment: for the moment dons't work, i really don't understand why, i am studing about but is really complicated. Thank you for help, i can offer you a bear or something to drink via paypal, because you are really friendly. 

I continue to search a solution i don't know why before it working and now no.... i am really sad

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without ajax and jQuery, using fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
<html><body>

<script>
var id = '13KmAf2uc13fWxPvn8dtk9j9kOL3nCVqi8H-wYau6Tww';
var gid = '0';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => document.getElementById("Vinorosato").innerHTML=myItems(data.match(/(?<="table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0]) 
  );
function myItems(jsonString){
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var table = '<table>'
  for (var i=0;i<json.rows.length;i++){
    var nome = json.rows[i].c[0].v;
    var ingredienti = json.rows[i].c[1].v;
    var prezzo = json.rows[i].c[2].v;
    table += '<tr><td>' + nome + '</td><td>' + ingredienti + '</td><td>' + prezzo + '&nbsp;&euro;</td></tr>'
  }
  table += '</table>'
  return table
}
</script>

<div id="Vinorosato">List ...</div>

</body></html>
```

https://codepen.io/mikesteelson/pen/YzQKere
For iOS compatibilty, use instead

```
<html><body>

<script>
var id = '13KmAf2uc13fWxPvn8dtk9j9kOL3nCVqi8H-wYau6Tww';
var gid = '0';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => document.getElementById("Vinorosato").innerHTML=myItems(data.substring(117).slice(0, -3))
  );
function myItems(jsonString){
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var table = '<table>'
  for (var i=0;i<json.rows.length;i++){
    var nome = json.rows[i].c[0].v;
    var ingredienti = json.rows[i].c[1].v;
    var prezzo = json.rows[i].c[2].v;
    table += '<tr><td>' + nome + '</td><td>' + ingredienti + '</td><td>' + prezzo + '&nbsp;&euro;</td></tr>'
  }
  table += '</table>'
  return table
}
</script>

<div id="Vinorosato">List ...</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: the console for iphone say: irregular expression i think is the ===  data.match(/(?=?table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0]  thath dosn't work with ios devices

Comment: maybe i have to use the jquery?

Comment: hum, try with only `.then(data => document.getElementById("Vinorosato").innerHTML=data` to be sure that match is the cause. Quite sure that fetch() doesn't work in iOs instead.

Comment: with only:  .then(data => document.getElementById("Vinorosato").innerHTML=data

Show some frases : 


google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"1939066001","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"","type":"string"},{"id":"C","label":"","type":"number","pattern":"\u0022\u20AC\u0022#,##0"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Antipasto misto di mare "},{"v":"frutti di mare"}....

I think is the match the cause, because also on iphone i read this frases with the datas

Comment: Yes for me the format of data.match is the problem, because with an iphone i can read the codes above, with  any browser which is on an iphone i can see this data. So my question is: is there another way to print the data? without ` /(?=?table":).*(?=});)/g)`

Comment: Try `__________.innerHTML=myItems(data.substring(117).slice(0, -3))` , if notOK, remove myItems and give me the exact response

Comment: ITS WORKINGGGGG! you are AMAZING ! please give me your email, my is:

andreavitiello95@gmail.com i want offer you a drink for all what you have done!! Via paypal

Comment: Thx a lot Vitiello, and good news for iOs and Google Sheets ... I will appreciate just a virtual coffee, thx very much. Offer it to a disabled person that you know on my own behalf !